# how to set proxy details using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, afnetworking

we recently use AFNetworking instead of ASIHttpRequest. But I cannot find any API in AFNetworking to set proxy details for a request as ASIHttpRequest offered. Could anyone give a help? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499173/proxy-server-routing-for-http-requests-with-afnetworking. That question was put on hold, so perhaps this should be as well.

Comment: @gtmtg - I don't think this question is quite as broad.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue now. Perhaps you can publish what kind of solution did you implemented eventually. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

AFNetworking uses NSURLRequest objects for the actual networking.

NSURLRequest does not support configurable HTTP proxies, except that it will of course follow the proxy server set up in your network preferences.

Possible solutions; none ideal:

1. Instruct your user what proxy to set up in settings
2. Create your own proxy support using the CFURLConnection classes
3. Use ASIHTTPRequest

You can also [submit an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple.

If you choose option #2, you might be able to wrap it in an NSOperation subclass and throw it into AFNetworking's operation queue.  I'm not sure if that would work though.  Either way, you might also be able to get some helpful code from the ASIHTTPRequest code base.

---

Update for AFNetworking / iOS 7:  If you use the *session instead of the *requestoperation interface, you can configure an HTTP Proxy using [`[NSURLSessionConfiguration -connectionProxyDictionary]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/).

Comment: Does `ASIHTTPRequest` support that? although it's not maintained anymore.

Comment: @Malloc - Yes, see http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use; search for "working with proxies"

Comment: I submitted an enhancement request for this (radar# 14442765).

Comment: Thank you~~ I'm on the option #2 now :)

Comment: @AaronBrager, It's been a while since you posted your answer, and I'm facing the same issue now. perhaps over the years, have you witnessed any change in AFNetworking that enables proxy configuration directly from AFNetworking ?

Comment: @Zohar81 Nope :(